# DynamoDb restore from PITR (Using Java SDK)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Does the AWS Dynamodb Java SDK support the creation of new Table from (Point in Time Restore) ?
Specifically asking if this is possible, so that I could have a lambda or java app create from PITR - and avoid the hassle of having tech-ops do this for me in PROD.

Thanks !

Comment: The AWS SDK does not support this. See the functionality here: https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/dynamodb/DynamoDbClient.html